# Msg ordering in PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am fairly new to PubSub and while reading the docs I came to know that PubSub doesn't guarantee the ordering of msgs. On future reading, I came to know the one way of ordering the msg is to manually create an ID and based on that order the msgs in the subscriber (Only of we one synchronize Publisher and one subscriber).

Is there any other way to maintain the order of messages in PubSub. Any help would be appreciated. An example would be also appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a description toward the end of this document: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering  and some example code for node.js is included.

Comment: Cloud Pub/Sub now [supports ordered delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering). The feature is in beta as of August 2020 and will ultimately move to GA.